# SOLR query return values but stats.countDistinct still missing

Tags: solr, count, statistics, distinct

Here is my solr query, the result has some values returned but cannot count distinct :

**`"stats.field":"deviceId"`**
**`"numFound":38`**
**`"deviceId":"11004084101MTVCN240D63C00010"`**
**`"missing":38`**
**`"distinctValues":[]`**

Here is the full response :

```
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 0,
    "params": {
      "q": "*:*",
      "stats.calcdistinct": "true",
      "indent": "on",
      "stats": "on",
      "start": "0",
      "fq": [
        "creationTime:[\"2018-10-19\" TO \"2018-10-19 23:59:59\"]",
        "tenant:mailink.MKH13.KVMB.DXHN1"
      ],
      "rows": "1",
      "wt": "json",
      "stats.field": "deviceId"
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "numFound": 38,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": [
      {
        "creationTime": "2018-10-19 21:13:55",
        "deviceId": "11004084101MTVCN240D63C00010",
        "tenant": "mailink.MKH13.KVMB.DXHN1",
        "status": 0,
        "id": "685b041f-91af-424f-9e9d-b06db9fbcd94",
        "_version_": 1614767301005934600
      }
    ]
  },
  "stats": {
    "stats_fields": {
      "deviceId": {
        "min": null,
        "max": null,
        "count": 0,
        "missing": 38,
        "distinctValues": [],
        "countDistinct": 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated :) Thanks!

Comment: What is the type of the field?

Comment: @MatsLindh: type of deviceId is String

Comment: Yes it's weird, there is at least 1 document with a deviceId so `count` and `missing` are false too.